# Match on generics

Tags: generics, rust, macros

i found out you can "match" over the type of a generic like so:

```rust
use std::any::Any;

trait SomeTrait {}

struct SomeStruct<T: SomeTrait> {
  atr: T,
}

struct Bar {
  name: String,
}

impl SomeTrait for Bar {}

struct Baz;
impl SomeTrait for Baz {}

fn foo<T: SomeTrait + 'static>(s: SomeStruct<T>) {
    let any: Box<dyn Any> = Box::new(s.atr);
    if let Some(bar) = any.downcast_ref::<Bar>() {
        println!("got bar! {:?}", bar.name);
    } else {
        println!("did not get bar");
    }
}

fn main() {
  foo::<Bar>(SomeStruct {
    atr: Bar { name: "hello".to_string() }
  });
  foo::<Baz>(SomeStruct { atr: Baz {} });
}
```

is there a crate or a  macro to do this?
i was imagining one macro that would look something like

```rust
fn foo<T: SomeTrait + 'static>(s: SomeStruct<T>) {
    generic_match! s.ty {
      Bar(bar) => println!("got bar! {:?}", bar.name),
      Baz => println!("did not get bar"),
    }
}
```

Comment: The macro-like syntax you proposed is not valid Rust. Besides, it's uncommon in Rust to use `Any` and `downcast_ref` at all, I don't think such a macro exists in the standard library.

Comment: Since the macro-like syntax in the question is not valid, you could instead consider creating an attribute macro for this. It can be applied directly to a match block.

Comment: Usually this is done as `fn f<T>(...) where T : Bar`.

Comment: i see. thank you for your help. i might look into making one in the future.